# i want that squid client cannot change or view the proxy setting in the browser

Tags: windows, proxy, squid

now i have a server in our domain.i will configure some of users on our domain and remaining some users will not be configured on domain.so i used squid proxy server for them and apply policies with the help of squid proxy server without adding them in a domain.so now i have configured every thing.i added the proxy into the clients browsers.and i think if they will search for proxy setting then they can remove the proxy.
kindly help me to find the way through squid proxy server that employees cannot access the browser setting or cannot remove the proxy.any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't prevent users changing the browser configuration. The only viable way to force users to use the proxy is to make it the only way to access outside resources. Block the traffic on the outgoing firewall and the users are forced to use the proxy.